# Hardware RAID not showing in Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, ubuntu-server

I've recently repurposed an older machine I had as a NAS.  I just added 4 HDDs to it intending to set them up as RAID 1+0.  This is an HP Proliant Microserver Gen8.  I set the drives up in the raid controller, but once booted, it shows as 4 individual drives instead of 1 logical drive.  What am I missing here?  I was sure it should show as one drive.

**lspci -v**

```
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Desktop SATA RAID Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Hewlett Packard Enterprise 6 Series/C200 Series Desktop SATA RAID Controller
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32, NUMA node 0
        I/O ports at 10c0 [size=8]
        I/O ports at 10c8 [size=4]
        I/O ports at 10d0 [size=8]
        I/O ports at 10d8 [size=4]
        I/O ports at 10e0 [size=32]
        Memory at facd0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci
```

**fdisk -l**

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000VN008-2DR1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000VN008-2DR1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sde: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000VN008-2DR1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdf: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000VN008-2DR1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to delete this post but I thought it better to put the information out there.  This "hardware raid" is *software supported*.  That is to say, you need to configure this raid beyond the "Smart Storage Administration" layer; from within the OS.  There is support for this in debian, however there is SO LITTLE support for this that I decided it would be smarter to go with a software raid for my use case.  Here is what I could find: https://www.jimmdenton.com/hp-raid-tools-ubuntu/